# split a string by any symbol

Tags: java, regex, symbols, split

What is the regex that I should pass with `String.split()` in order to split the string by any **symbol**?

Now, by any **symbol** I mean any of the following:

```
`~`, `!`, `@`, `#`, ...
```

Basically any non-letter and non-digit printable character.

Comment: Do you mean any non alphanumeric character?

Comment: `.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a non word i.e `\W`

`\W` is inverse of `\w`

`\W` is similar to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` and so would match any non-word character except `_`

**OR**

you can simply use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`

Answer (score 4):

You can try using this: -

```
str.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
```

This will not include an `underscore`.

`\W` is equivalent to: - `"[a-zA-Z0-9_]"`

Comment: `[_^\w]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Oh. Then how would we remove `_` from it?

Comment: The caret carries no special meaning if it's not the first character; so what you have is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_\^]`

Comment: @NullUserException. Yeah exactly. So I removed it. Is there any way to use `\W` without `_`?

Answer (score 1):

You could either be specific like `Spring.split("[~!@$]")` or list the values you do not want to split upon `Spring.split("[^\\w]")`

Comment: `[^\w] == \W == [^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so it includes the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `\W` or `^\w`. You may find more details here: [**Regex: Character classes**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)

```
    String str = "a@v$d!e";
    String[] splitted = str.split("\\W");
    System.out.println(splitted.length); //<--print 4
```

or

```
    String str = "a@v$d!e";
    String[] splitted = str.split("[^\\w]");
    System.out.println(splitted.length); //<--print 4
```

Comment: `[\\W]` is redundant, why not just `\\W`?

Comment: @NullUserException: I started putting different pattern e.g. `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` then replaced with `\W` :) Removed the braces.